# Tensorflow 2.3 -TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'> when using .get_session().run(tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, yolo

I have a yolo_non_max_suppression method as shown below:

```
  def yolo_non_max_suppression(scores, boxes, classes, max_boxes = 10, iou_threshold = 0.5):
    max_boxes_tensor = K.variable(value=max_boxes, dtype='int32')
    print("printing max_boxes_tensor:",max_boxes_tensor)
    print("Data type:",K.dtype(max_boxes_tensor))
    init= tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer([max_boxes_tensor])
    print("printing tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer:",init)
    K.get_session().run(init))
    
    nms_indices = tf.image.non_max_suppression(boxes, scores, max_boxes_tensor, 
    iou_threshold=iou_threshold)
   
    scores = K.gather(scores, nms_indices)
    boxes = K.gather(boxes, nms_indices)
    classes = K.gather(classes, nms_indices)
    
    return scores, boxes, classes
```

When I test the above code out using the following test stub:

```
   with tf.compat.v1.Session() as test_b:
    scores = tf.random.normal([54,], mean=1, stddev=4, seed = 1)
    boxes = tf.random.normal([54, 4], mean=1, stddev=4, seed = 1)
    classes = tf.random.normal([54,], mean=1, stddev=4, seed = 1)
    scores, boxes, classes = yolo_non_max_suppression(scores, boxes, classes)
    print("scores[2] = " + str(scores[2].eval()))
    print("boxes[2] = " + str(boxes[2].eval()))
    print("classes[2] = " + str(classes[2].eval()))
    print("scores.shape = " + str(scores.eval().shape))
    print("boxes.shape = " + str(boxes.eval().shape))
    print("classes.shape = " + str(classes.eval().shape))
```

The get the following output:

```
  max_boxes= 10
printing max_boxes_tensor: <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=int32>
Data type: int32
printing tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer: name: "init"
op: "NoOp"
input: "^Variable/Assign"

scores[2] = 6.938395
boxes[2] = [-5.299932    3.1379814   4.450367    0.95942086]
classes[2] = -2.2452729
scores.shape = (10,)
boxes.shape = (10, 4)
classes.shape = (10,)
```

I now try to invoke the above method from yolo_eval as shown below:-

```
def yolo_eval(yolo_outputs, image_shape = (720., 1280.), max_boxes=10, score_threshold=.6, iou_threshold=.5):

    box_confidence, box_xy, box_wh, box_class_probs = yolo_outputs
    boxes = yolo_boxes_to_corners(box_xy, box_wh)
    scores, boxes, classes = yolo_filter_boxes(box_confidence, boxes, box_class_probs, threshold = score_threshold)
    boxes = scale_boxes(boxes, image_shape)
    # here i invoke the above implemented yolo_non_max_suppression
    #scores, boxes, classes = yolo_non_max_suppression(scores, boxes, classes, max_boxes = max_boxes, iou_threshold = iou_threshold)
    scores, boxes, classes = yolo_non_max_suppression(scores, boxes, classes)  
    return scores, boxes, classes
```

The tested the above  yolo_eval method using my test stub:

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as test_b:
    yolo_outputs = (tf.random.normal([19, 19, 5, 1], mean=1, stddev=4, seed = 1),
                    tf.random.normal([19, 19, 5, 2], mean=1, stddev=4, seed = 1),
                    tf.random.normal([19, 19, 5, 2], mean=1, stddev=4, seed = 1),
                    tf.random.normal([19, 19, 5, 80], mean=1, stddev=4, seed = 1))
    scores, boxes, classes = yolo_eval(yolo_outputs)
    print("scores[2] = " + str(scores[2].eval()))
    print("boxes[2] = " + str(boxes[2].eval()))
    print("classes[2] = " + str(classes[2].eval()))
    print("scores.shape = " + str(scores.eval().shape))
    print("boxes.shape = " + str(boxes.eval().shape))
    print("classes.shape = " + str(classes.eval().shape))
```

I get the following output:

```
max_boxes= 10
printing max_boxes_tensor: <tf.Variable 'Variable_1:0' shape=() dtype=int32>
Data type: int32
printing tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer: name: "init_3"
op: "NoOp"
input: "^Variable_1/Assign"

scores[2] = 138.79124
boxes[2] = [1292.3297  -278.52167 3876.9893  -835.56494]
classes[2] = 54
scores.shape = (10,)
boxes.shape = (10, 4)
classes.shape = (10,)
```

So far, so good. However when I test the pretrained model on images ( exactly as per Andrew's coursera assignment with absolute zero deviation, except for upgrading the code to tensorflow 2.3) , things start to behave differently.

```
sess = K.get_session()
class_names = read_classes("model_data/coco_classes.txt")
anchors = read_anchors("model_data/yolo_anchors.txt")
image_shape = (720., 1280.) yolo_model = load_model(model_dir)
yolo_model.summary() # no issues here..

yolo_outputs = yolo_head(yolo_model.output, anchors, len(class_names)) # another library method available as part of the assignment
print(yolo_outputs)
```

Giving the following output:

```
(<tf.Tensor 'Sigmoid:0' shape=(None, None, None, 5, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'RealDiv:0' shape=(None, None, None, 5, 2) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'RealDiv_1:0' shape=(None, None, None, 5, 2) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'Softmax:0' shape=(None, None, None, 5, 80) dtype=float32>)
```

Now I call my previously implemented yolo_eval as shown below:

```
scores, boxes, classes = yolo_eval(yolo_outputs, image_shape)
```

**This where I get the following error:**

```
max_boxes= 10
printing max_boxes_tensor: <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=int32, numpy=10>
Data type: int32
printing tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer: None

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-1c93a2e863cf> in <module>
----> 1 scores, boxes, classes = yolo_eval(yolo_outputs, image_shape)

<ipython-input-9-86120a47e84f> in yolo_eval(yolo_outputs, image_shape, max_boxes, score_threshold, iou_threshold)
     37     # Use one of the functions you've implemented to perform Non-max suppression with a threshold of iou_threshold (≈1 line)
     38     #scores, boxes, classes = yolo_non_max_suppression(scores, boxes, classes, max_boxes = max_boxes, iou_threshold = iou_threshold)
---> 39     scores, boxes, classes = yolo_non_max_suppression(scores, boxes, classes)
     40 
     41     ### END CODE HERE ###

<ipython-input-7-f4ff9df30d44> in yolo_non_max_suppression(scores, boxes, classes, max_boxes, iou_threshold)
     25     print("Data type:",K.dtype(max_boxes_tensor))
     26     print("printing tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer:",tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer([max_boxes_tensor]))
---> 27     K.get_session().run(tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer([max_boxes_tensor]))
     28     #K.get_session().run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
     29 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    955 
    956     try:
--> 957       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
    958                          run_metadata_ptr)
    959       if run_metadata:

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1163 
   1164     # Create a fetch handler to take care of the structure of fetches.
-> 1165     fetch_handler = _FetchHandler(
   1166         self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)
   1167 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __init__(self, graph, fetches, feeds, feed_handles)
    475     """
    476     with graph.as_default():
--> 477       self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
    478     self._fetches = []
    479     self._targets = []

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in for_fetch(fetch)
    260     """
    261     if fetch is None:
--> 262       raise TypeError('Fetch argument %r has invalid type %r' %
    263                       (fetch, type(fetch)))
    264     elif isinstance(fetch, (list, tuple)):

TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

What stands out is that the **tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer** return **None** this time around. Not sure why. I am going nuts trying to get some clue.

Comment: I got same issue. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: I managed to solve it. I wanted to paste my code here but unfortunately I am unable to start my VM in GCP due to some resource issues. I will post the answer once I get it going. thanks for the patience.

Comment: @user3014926, please see my answer below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it as follows:

```
 with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
   class_names = read_classes("model_data/coco_classes.txt")
   anchors = read_anchors("model_data/yolo_anchors.txt")
   image_shape = (720., 1280.)    
   model_dir=os.path.join("./model_data/","yolo.h5")
   print(model_dir)
   print(os.path.isfile(model_dir))
   h5 = h5py.File(model_dir,'r')
   yolo_model = load_model(model_dir)
   yolo_outputs = yolo_head(yolo_model.output, anchors, len(class_names))
   print(yolo_outputs)
   scores, boxes, classes = yolo_eval(yolo_outputs, image_shape)
   out_scores, out_boxes, out_classes = predict(sess,yolo_model,"cars3.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use with statement instead of `sess = K.get_session()`.

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    class_names = read_classes("model_data/coco_classes.txt")
    anchors = read_anchors("model_data/yolo_anchors.txt")
    image_shape = (720., 1280.)    
    yolo_model = load_model("model_data/yolo.h5")
    yolo_outputs = yolo_head(yolo_model.output, anchors, len(class_names))
    print(yolo_outputs)
    scores, boxes, classes = yolo_eval(yolo_outputs, image_shape)
    out_scores, out_boxes, out_classes = predict(sess,"test.jpg")
```

Comment: Can you explain how your answer differs *significantly* from [that posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64980017/10871073)?